# Create many app from single source code

Tags: android, xcode

I have build one app and I want to give the same app to other clients with just some App color and Logo change.
Right now my code is on bitbucket. First I thought like keeping the app's source code of different client on different branches. But I don't think it's good way.

In Android we have something called flavour in gradle.
What do I do in iOS? Currently am using XCode 9.1

Please suggest me a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this link http://www.itexico.com/blog/bid/99497/iOS-Mobile-Development-Using-Xcode-Targets-to-Reuse-the-Code

I'll try this out.

Comment: I am sorry Anirudha Mahale but you have to post some details from that link or your answer will be of low quality and probably get closed as useless for future readers! What if the link is dead next year? Edit your answer or delete the question!